# insert field with cr/lf

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

How do I handle this situation.

I have a mysql backend that contains a field that is, let's say, 40 characters long.

I have a textarea form field that I have set to maxlength="40"

I have implemented some jquery code that counts the characters as you type them.

As I enter text I can see the character counter going down, showing me how many characters are left. When it reaches 0 I will have supposedly entered 40 characters.

The problem is that the counter and the textarea maxlength checks are only counting the carriage return/line feeds as one character. If I fill the textarea, with any CR's, and I try to insert the text into mysql it, of course, chokes, because there are too many characters.

Is there some kind of filtering I need to do when I write/read it to the DB? I don't want to just truncate the text at the max characters when I do the insert/update.

Comment: use `trim` before sending it to the server.

Comment: Trim just removes whitespace from beginning and ending of a line. I have paragraphs with multiple sentences, resulting in multiple cases of the issue.

Comment: On the client, see if you can get your js to count two characters for a carraige return.  On the server, make sure data passes muster before you attempt to send it to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps just do a `str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $whatever_variable);`.  You'll maintain where the new line is, and you can easily convert it back to "\r\n" if needed.

Comment: It kind of appears that this would be a good use of str_replace. I have allowed the textarea field to accept more than the max characters though, with a warning. My counter seems to have an issue when backspacing so I also trim the data to the DB field size to make sure I get no errors from the UPDATE and INSERTs. `substr(str_replace("\r\n","\n",$event_desc),0,40)`